# Laravel with teradata

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection, teradata

I have a laravel project that is currently linked to the default database which is MySQL, the current issue I'm facing, I didn't find the steps for linking Laravel with Teradata

FYI

I checked but I wasn't able to implement the same in laravel

https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/php-with-teradata-odbc

and

https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc

Comment: Did you look into this package ? https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc

Comment: yeah but i didn't able to implement it unfortunately

Comment: What exactly the issue are you facing ? can you please post code or screenshot ? because if something is not integrating is very broad way of looking at it, tell us why it's not working ? what all are the methods have you tried to implement it ?

Comment: for example: i have the default DB comes with Teradata VM server
http://prnt.sc/prifmc

the table is DBC.allrights

and i want to get the results in 

http://prnt.sc/priglo

and this is the paramenters i used:

http://prnt.sc/prih1z

and this is the tutorial is refer to https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc

this is the output:
http://prnt.sc/prihkk

Comment: Current settings:
[link 1](https://paste.pics/113342a7160551c3a8e50a8ede3090bf)
[link 2](https://paste.pics/610407c8dbe14628e6208c50b4c694a0)
[link 3](https://paste.pics/5066545d3505336fc56533a3065b8b61)
[link 4](https://paste.pics/2cf600936796e373389f76bf1ce48662)
[link 5](https://paste.pics/34a3bf4c402b3058376b2d6535012336)